How do I set my project JAVA_HOME to my computers JAVA_HOME?
I have an Flutter app in android studio on my Mac and I accidentally reset my JAVA_HOME path in my project trying to update java for my project.
This gives me the error:
JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: Users/{My UserName}/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-23.0.1

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

To find my java version and location I ran the following command in my terminal:
/usr/libexec/java_home -V

returned:
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.7.45.18 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

I then opened my .zshrc file and added the following lines:
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.45.18)

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

To confirm the path I ran:
echo $JAVA_HOME

returned:
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

When trying to build my app again I get the same error I got before.
So I tried running the following command inside of my app directory terminal:
export JAVA_HOME=“/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home”

returned:
export: not valid in this context: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

I don't understand what this error means.
How do I set my project JAVA_HOME to my computers JAVA_HOME?
EDIT:  g00se and John Bollinger have pointed out that my error is probably in Android studio.  So I downloaded a new JDK in Android studio (File > Project Structure...)

I reset my JAVA_HOME path in my .zshrc file to match my new jdk file path.
running flutter run still gives me the error :
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: Users/{MyName}/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-23.0.1

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

fluttor doctor -v gives me the error:
 Java binary at: Users/{MyName}/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-23.0.1/bin/java
    ✗ Cannot execute Users/{MyName}/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-23.0.1/bin/java to determine the version

Update:
flutter analyze --suggestions returns
[✗] Java/Gradle/Android Gradle Plugin:
 Incompatible Java/Gradle versions.
 Java Version: null, Gradle Version: 7.6.3

So even though I am getting the same JAVA_HOME paths from echo $JAVA_HOME and what I see in my project structure inside of android studio I'm getting a null Java version here...

In export $JAVA_HOME you don't need $.

What do you mean by "I tried running the following command inside of my app"?

returned: export: not valid in this context: That's a shell command and therefore only valid in the context of the shell. It has no place inside an 'app'. The question is why your dev environment is not using the correct env. var. Learn how to start it in the console and it should

I meant from the terminal, but inside of my app home directory.

I meant from the terminal, but inside of my app home directory. That's not going to have any effect on an already running gui dev environment. Start that environment from the terminal

when i enter the command flutter run from my terminal I get the error : Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

If your edit is not working it suggests that you might be using a different shell. What does echo $SHELL say?

I get /bin/zsh when I enter echo $SHELL

echo $JAVA_HOME is now returning just /Users/{MYNAME}/Library/Internet  Maybe the space in my Internet Plug-Ins path is causing issues.  Edit: when i entered the command again it returned the same path?!?

I don't use Android Studio, but it sounds like you may have set a Java home directory as a project-specific property there.  If so, then you probably need to fix the issue there, too.

What @JohnBollinger is saying makes sense. If you have set a property in your IDE, then unsetting it would probably cause it to use the shell's variable

After making sure my JAVA_HOME paths were compatible my final issue was caused by incompatible Java and Gradle versions.
See Compatibility Matrix.  I had installed jdk 23, which was incompatible with gradle 7.6.
In Android Studio: File > Project Structure > Add New SDK > Download JDK...
Select the compatible version for you, in my case 19.


Open .zshrc in a text editor:
nano ~/.zshrc


Add the path to your Java installation at the end of the file. Replace the path below if your Java version or installation location is different:
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home


Alternative Method: If the above path doesn't work, you can use macOS’s java_home utility to set JAVA_HOME automatically:
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)


Save the changes and reload .zshrc to apply:
source ~/.zshrc


After completing these steps, you can check that JAVA_HOME is set correctly by running:
echo $JAVA_HOME



This should display the path to your Java installation.

Thanks I did this, however I am still running into problems as per my edit.  I believe this is an Android Studio / Flutter issue

you should go to your system>>enviorment variables>>click on the edit enviorment variables and then edit the existing path variables.
If you want you could even watch the tutorial about this in detail;

You mentioned a tutorial, but didn't leave a link.
